# Spring + Tomcat: Wrong Driver Class is loaded, how to debug?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

I have a `datasource` bean which looks like

```
@Override
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setUrl(getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(getUser());
        if (!getPassword().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataSource.setPassword(getPassword());
        }

        LOGGER.debug("DriverClass={}, URL={}, User={}", getDriverClassName(), getUrl(), getUser());
        return dataSource;
    }
```

When I see in logs I see log as

```
09:09:28.874 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG c.y.c.p.profiles.MySqlDatabaseConfig - DriverClass=java.database.jdbc.mysql.MyWrapper, URL=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/pryme, User=app_user
```

The `MyWrapper` class is encrypted class to get secure key. but I see error in logs as

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'app_user'@'62.117.121.130' (using password: YES))
```

All the way at the end, I see line as

```
09:09:31,367 ERROR [WebappClassLoader] The web application [/common] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

But I never registered this class `[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]`

**More Context**
The properties comes to the bean with following rule

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:properties/default.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/home/y/conf/app/app.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class MySqlDatabaseConfig extends JpaCommonConfig {
```

Where `default.properties` look like

```
database_driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database_url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pryme?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
database_username=root
database_password=
```

but on server, I do have `/home/y/conf/app/app.properties` which has line

```
database_driverClassName: java.database.jdbc.mysql.MyWrapper
```

I do not going whats going on right now

Comment: The fact that `default.properties` is declared first may mean that it will be used first. Also note that JDBC 4 drivers are registered automatically.

Comment: The reason of having two `@PropertySource` is that latter one overrides the property available in first

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The source code for `@Configuration` class processing uses a `Set` which isn't ordered. In any case, we can see your log which shows that your custom class is used. I would investigate the JDBC 4 driver automatically registering itself.